# @Autowired Not Working with XML Configuration Spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a simple `beans.xml` file as below.

It has two beans :

**Employee and 
Address**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="address" class="com.atul.test.Address"></bean> 

    <bean id="employee" class="com.atul.test.Employee"> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have below Java Classes and Configuration.

```
public class Employee {

    @Autowired
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void checkAddress(){

        System.out.println("Your address is = "+this.address);
        this.address.vomit();


    }   
}
```

```
public class Address {

    public void vomit(){
        System.out.println("Vomit !!!!");
    }

}
```

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        Employee employee = (Employee)ctx.getBean("employee");

        System.out.println("Employee = "+employee);
        Address address = (Address)ctx.getBean("address");
        System.out.println("address = "+address);

        System.out.println("employee.address = "+employee.getAddress());

    }
}
```

The issue :

1. Even though , I have `@Autowired` on **Employee** class , **Address** is not getting injected
2. I am getting `employee.address` as NULL
3. `ctx.getBean("employee")` and `ctx.getBean("address")` both are returning correct beans `(non null)`
4. As per my understanding , `@Autowired` should work as long as both beans are available in `Spring context` , which is true in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `<context:annotation-config/>` in you spring XML to enable Spring annotation.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="address" class="com.atul.test.Address"></bean>

    <bean id="employee" class="com.atul.test.Employee"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score -2):

You must use `@Component` on your class Address

```
@Component
public class Address {

    public void vomit(){
        System.out.println("Vomit !!!!");
    }

}
```

You must use `@Component` on all class that you want to use with autowired

Comment: `@Component` is not required since the bean is defined in the XML.

Comment: Adding `@Component` won't add a thing. The beans are configured in XML and no component-scanning is being done.